# Should there be a comma before too (at the end of the sentence) if the sentence already has commas?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

According to many sources, like Grammarly's [blog](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma-before-too/), you can omit the comma before *too*.

This got me thinking, how about sentences like these?

> Come to think of it, Tom was angry, and Mark was mad too.

This makes it looks like *too* is only related to *Mark was mad*. But if you write:

> Come to think of it, Tom was angry, and Mark was mad, too.

Then *too* seems to belong to the whole sentence.

Am I right? Is this a known rule? (I have the same doubt with after all, either, etc.)

Comment: To include Tom, I'd remove the comma after *angry* and keep that after *mad*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of style, not grammar. Depending on what source you refer to, you will get different guidance.

The following is what [*The Chicago Manual of Style* (17th ed.), 6.52](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch06/psec052.html), says on the subject:

> The adverbs *too* and *either* used in the sense of “also” generally need not be preceded by a comma.
>
> I had my cake and ate it too.
>         Anders likes Beethoven; his sister does too.
>         The airport lacked charging stations; there were no comfortable chairs either.
>
> When *too* comes in the middle of the sentence or clause, however, a comma aids comprehension.
>
> She, too, decided against the early showing.

Personally, that's the advice I follow. In the past, I would put a comma before a final *too* in a sentence, but I've since changed that style.

However, doing it differently is certainly not incorrect.

---

Like when using a pronoun, the context of its use can be ambiguous. If you find that something is ambiguous, you can use different punctuation (perhaps adding a comma or removing it makes the meaning more clear) or you can rephrase the sentence altogether.